# Firebase InApp Messaging messages stopped coming, unable to update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

Firebase InApp Messaging test messages stopped coming on real devices, they are only received on emulator. I decided to update from 17.0.1 to latest version 17.0.4.

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.4'

However, I get this error when building

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: This method com/google/firebase/inappmessaging/internal/ProtoStorageClient.lambda$read$1(Lcom/google/firebase/inappmessaging/internal/ProtoStorageClient;Lcom/google/protobuf/Parser;)Lcom/google/protobuf/AbstractMessageLite; has a call to $closeResource(Throwable, AutoCloseable) method, but the type inference is null.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:1079)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.TryWithResourcesRewriter$TryWithResourceVisitor.visitMethodInsn(TryWithResourcesRewriter.java:285)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(MethodVisitor.java:485)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.ObjectsRequireNonNullMethodRewriter$ObjectsMethodInlinerMethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(ObjectsRequireNonNullMethodRewriter.java:55)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(MethodVisitor.java:485)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LongCompareMethodRewriter$LongCompareMethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(LongCompareMethodRewriter.java:52)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(MethodVisitor.java:485)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Java7Compatibility$UpdateBytecodeVersionIfNecessary.visitMethodInsn(Java7Compatibility.java:148)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn(MethodVisitor.java:485)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring$InterfaceInvocationRewriter.visitMethodInsn(InterfaceDesugaring.java:423)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1600)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
```

:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug FAILED

Comment: You also need to update the rest of your Google dependencies.

Comment: I have updated all Firebase and Google play services dependencies to latest versions and error is still there.

Comment: Including those in your project level build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `minSdkVersion` from `17` to `21` and this error went away.